What is the meaning of actual rows using explain analyze in mysql
In my sql
 explain analyze select
        ep1_0.employee_post_id,
        ep1_0.access_url,
        ep1_0.contact,
        ep1_0.contents,
        ep1_0.member_id,
        ep1_0.payment_amount,
        ep1_0.payment_method,
        ep1_0.title,
        ep1_0.career_year,
        ep1_0.created_at,
        ep1_0.updated_at 
    from
        employee_post ep1_0 
     join
         member m1_0 
             on m1_0.member_id=ep1_0.member_id 
    where
        ep1_0.work_field_tag_id=1
    order by
        ep1_0.created_at desc,
        ep1_0.employee_post_id desc 
    limit
        0,1;

I tried this query(above) and I got answer(below)
-> Limit: 1 row(s)  (cost=1088 rows=1) (actual time=23.8..23.8 rows=1 loops=1)
    -> Nested loop inner join  (cost=1088 rows=1968) (actual time=23.8..23.8 rows=1 loops=1)
        -> Sort: ep1_0.created_at DESC, ep1_0.employee_post_id DESC  (cost=399 rows=1968) (actual time=23.8..23.8 rows=1 loops=1)
            -> Index lookup on ep1_0 using FK_work_field_tag_TO_employee_post (work_field_tag_id=1)  (cost=399 rows=1968) (actual time=0.069..5.12 rows=1968 loops=1)
        -> Single-row covering index lookup on m1_0 using PRIMARY (member_id=ep1_0.member_id)  (cost=0.25 rows=1) (actual time=0.0262..0.0262 rows=1 loops=1)

I cannot understand the meaning of the "actual rows" value in parentheses in MySQL.
In a nested loop inner join,
does "actual rows = 1" mean that only one row is actually joined?
If so, does that mean the JOIN is processed after applying the LIMIT clause?

In EXPLAIN ANALYZE, actual rows=1 in the Nested Loop Join means only 1 row was output by the join after applying all conditions.
The JOIN is processed before LIMIT, but execution stops as soon as LIMIT 1 is satisfied.

Does "The JOIN is processed before LIMIT, but execution stops as soon as LIMIT 1 is satisfied." means that only one row is actually joined?
